# bootstrap 3 column layout, main content before two sidebar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap, for the both left and right sidebar 3 column layout, we don't know how to edit the css to put the main content above both sidebars, please advise how to do, thanks.

We tried following code, but Not working:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6">
    main content
  </div>
  <div class="span3 pull-left">
    left bar
  </div>
  <div class="span3 pull-right">
    right bar
  </div>
</div>
```

please advise how to do it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** The solution below refered to the original question which was using Bootstrap 2

Part of the solution is to use pull-right on the main content, though doing this alone floats the main content to the far right of the window.

The full solution is to also use a nested grid for the main content and left bar so that the pull-right is contained.

See this live: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/mU2zu/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">

       <div class="span9">
           <div class="row">
         <div class="span6 pull-right">main content</div>

          <div class="span3">left bar</div>
           </div><!-- end nested row -->
    </div><!-- end span9 -->

        <div class="span3">right bar</div>

    </div><!-- end parent row-->

 </div><!-- end container -->
```

Good luck!

Comment: Your fiddle uses v2.2.2 of bootstrap the markup has changed considerably since then and the question relates to v3

Comment: @tcnarss , I get your point about the change in markup, but if you check the timeline for this question it was asked in Jan and I answered in Feb, 5 months before the first Bootstrap 3 RC version was released. The question was initially for boostrap 2 and then changed at a later date

Comment: Reverted my downvote due to edit! Just thought it was confusing before.

Comment: Thanks @tcnarss, I would never have know that the question had been changed if it wasn't for your comment.